# Laravel: How to filter models based on accessor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my Product model, I have defined an accessor that returns the average rating of the product.

The accessor looks like this:

```
public function getAverageRatingAttribute(){
    if($this->reviews->count()){
        $count = 0;
        $rating = 0;
        foreach ($this->reviews as $review) {
           if($review->average_rating){
                $rating += $review->average_rating;
                $count++;
           }
        }
        return $rating/$count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, in my controller I want to filter results based on average_rating attribute. Something like this:

```
$products->where('average_rating', '>=', $rating);
```

The following error occurs.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'average_rating' in 'where clause'
```

What will be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Create a field in a database and update it everytime someone rates an item.

Comment: You could also create a view and let the database update the average automatically for you.